# Push down div when above div expands?

Tags: html, css

Making a single page website. The HTML is as follows

```
<!-- Landing Page-->
    <div id="landing">
        <img src="front.png" alt="Cover Page">
    </div>
    <!-- About -->
    <div id="page1">
      <a id="about"></a>
        <img src="Who.png" alt="About Me">
        <p>
            xxx
        </p>
    </div>

    <!-- Work -->
    <div id="page2">
      <a id="portfolio"></a>
        <div id="container">
            <a class="fancybox" href="portfolio1.jpg" title="'Consumed' </br>Digital/Print Work"><img src="portfolio1s.png"/></a>
</div>
    </div>

    <!-- Contact -->
    <div id="page3">
      <a id="contact"></a>
        <img src="Contact.png" alt="Contact Information">
        <p>
            xxx
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

I removed the image links from the div #container, but altogether there are more than 10. My issue is when I make the window narrow (to see how it will be viewed on a mobile device), the images in div #container overlap with my image on my contact page. I would like it such that when it expands, it pushes the contact page down. I've tried doing this with position:relative, but doesn't seem to work.

Relevant CSS:

```
#container
{
padding:50px;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:center;
width:auto;
}

#container a img
{
padding:10px;
opacity:1.0;
filter:alpha (opacity=100); /*for >IE8 */
}

#page1 img 
{
display:block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:400px;    
position:relative;
top:15px;
}

#page2 {
height:1200px;
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
color:purple;
}

#page3 {
height:1200px;
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
color:red;
}

#page3 img
{
display:block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-bottom:-20px;
width:400px;
position:relative;
top:15px;
}
```

Comment: The first thing I notice is that you haven't closed the `div#container` div. Is that just a typo?

Comment: Ah yes, it is a typo. i deleted it by accident while deleting the image links.

Comment: Try creating a jsfiddle.net and recreate your problem and attach the layout image of the site

Comment: There is an error in your <a class="fancybox" href="portfolio1.jpg" title="'Consumed' </br> line, you should not use html tags inside the title attribute, use a "\n" instead.

Comment: @axel thanks for spotting that! i'm new to this so i'm making a lot of mistakes here and there